# Imagick PDF to JPG - Missing Images

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need to convert uploaded PDF's to Jpegs when the page is viewed. Most of them work but every now and then, some of the images aren't visible.
As it works most of the time I believe that it has something to do with the individual PDF's, but I would like to be able to code to include these inconsistencies.

Below is the PHP code:

```
$print_jpegs = glob($pathinfo["dirname"] . "/print_jpegs/" . $pathinfo["filename"] . "-*.jpg");

            if (count($print_jpegs) <= 0) {
                if (!file_exists($pathinfo["dirname"] . "/print_jpegs/")) {
                    mkdir($pathinfo["dirname"] . "/print_jpegs/", 0777, true);
                }

                $pdf = new Imagick($packages[$j]);
                $pages = $pdf->getNumberImages();
                $pdf->destroy();

                if ($pages > 0) {
                    for ($k = 0; $k < $pages && $k <= 10; $k++) {
                        $print_jpeg = $pathinfo["dirname"] . "/print_jpegs/" . $pathinfo["filename"] . "-" . $k . ".jpg";

                        $im = new Imagick();
                        $im->setResolution(150, 150);
                        $im->readImage($packages[$j] . "[" . $k . "]");
                        $im->setImageColorspace(imagick::COLORSPACE_RGB);
                        $im->flattenImages();

                        $d = $im->getImageGeometry();

                        $max_w = 794;   // 210mm @ 96ppi (A4)
                        $max_h = 1123;  // 297mm @ 96ppi (A4)

                        $ratio = $d["width"] / $d["height"];

                        if ($max_w / $max_h > $ratio) {
                            $w = $max_h * $ratio;
                            $h = $max_h;
                        } else {
                            $w = $max_w;
                            $h = $max_w / $ratio;
                        }

                        $im->resizeImage($w, $h, imagick::FILTER_SINC, 1, false);
                        $im->setImageCompression(imagick::COMPRESSION_JPEG);
                        $im->setImageCompressionQuality(100);
                        $im->setImageFormat("jpeg");
                        $im->writeImage($print_jpeg);
                        $im->clear();
                        $im->destroy();

                        $print_jpegs[] = $print_jpeg;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: hello, did you came up with a solution? I'm in the same exact situation...

Comment: Post your original PDF so we can test with it?